# Angular and Spring Boot Application Deployment

Tags: angular, spring-boot, web-deployment

I developed a web application which using `Angular` for the `Front-end` and `SpringBoot` as the `Back-end`. We usually deploy the app like this:

1. Use the `ng-build` on the `Angular` application;
2. Copy the built files into the `springboot`'s project static folder;
3. Use `maven` to build the `springboot` project;
4. Basically copy the `.jar` file to a PC (call this a server) and run the application.

**My question is that what would be the more professional way to deploy these apps ? What technologies should I looking for?**

Thanks!

Comment: You can pack your angular app in a ```jar``` file and include it as a dependency in spring-boot ```application```.

Answer (score 0):

Just google the solution. You can use `maven-resource-plugin` for example.

Resource:
https://dzone.com/articles/building-a-web-app-using-spring-boot-angular-6-and